# Vanilla javascript for loop inside another for loop adding same class to all divs

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've been look at this piece of javascript for hours and can't determine why every time i hover over rewardImg, it adds the class open to every offer div.

Any ideas? I understand it has something to do with closures or maybe i need to put it into an array?

```
var offer = document.querySelectorAll(".offer");
var rewardImg = document.querySelectorAll(".rewardImg");

for(var i = 0; i < rewardImg.length; i++) {
    rewardImg[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        for(var j = 0; j < offer.length; j++) {
            offer[j].classList.add("open");
        }
    });
}

for(var i = 0; i < rewardImg.length; i++) {
    rewardImg[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        for(var j = 0; j < offer.length; j++) {
            offer[j].classList.remove("open");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You iterate over the whole list of `offer` so why do you expect that it should only add it to certain elements of that list?

Comment: @eisbehr Using `i` in the callback won't work as the `i` is the same for all callbacks, because of the closure.

Comment: If you already asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510973) earlier, and it was closed as duplicated and you re-ask it again, then you should mention that you already asked it, and explain why you think that it is a different problem. It clearly is but you should mention the previous question.

Comment: That's true ... @t.niese

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @skyline3000 the OP does **not** use the `i ` within the callback. In the current form it is not a closure problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510973): What you need to do is perform the selection based on the rewardImg.

```js
var rewardImgs = document.querySelectorAll(".rewardImg");

for (var i = 0; i < rewardImgs.length; i++) {
  rewardImgs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        var offer = this.parentElement.querySelector(".offer");
        offer.classList.add("open");
   });

   rewardImgs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        var offer = this.parentElement.querySelector(".offer");
        offer.classList.remove("open");
   });

}
```

```css
.rewardImg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.offer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.offer.open {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="offer">
</div>
<div class="rewardImg">
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="offer">
</div>
<div class="rewardImg">
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="offer">
</div>
<div class="rewardImg">
</div>
</div>
```

This works because in the callback `this` is bound to the element that triggers the event (in this case: the element being hovered), hence we can find other DOM elements from there.

Comment: thank you so much that is exactly what I was looking for! makes so much sense. thanks for taking the time to explain it as well!

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are adding the class to all available `offer` via the for loop so make sure you add that to only the required elements.

Vanilla and no for loop solution will be something like -

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == 'offer') {
    var
      seq = '.rewardImg[data-seq="' + e.target.dataset.seq + '"]';
    
    var selected = document.querySelector(seq);
    selected.classList.add("open");
  }
});


document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == 'offer') {
    var
      seq = '.rewardImg[data-seq="' + e.target.dataset.seq + '"]';
    
    var selected = document.querySelector(seq);
    selected.classList.remove("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.open {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='offer' data-seq='1'>1</div>
<div class='offer' data-seq='2'>2</div>
<div class='rewardImg' data-seq='1'>11</div>
<div class='rewardImg' data-seq='2'>22</div>
```

Make a note that all that javascript must go in on an `on-load` event

Comment: thank you for your help. yes i do put my code into an onload event. just didnt add that into the question =)